# Microsoft Odata Performance improvements in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata

Recently, one of our clients asked us to look into improving our Odata requests, as he is performing a lot of requests(around one million) to get information from the DB or update some data and it's taking a lot of time(10-12 hours). We tried upgrading our Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData libraries from version 6 to a newer version (7.5.7) but the time improvement was minimal.
We have a customised Odata endpoint solution written in C# which is using a dynamic model creation approach(something similar to [DynamicEdmModelCreation](https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/tree/e76d1072616146fe416946aae67c6279ce339d6d/WebApiClassic/DynamicEdmModelCreation/DynamicEdmModelCreation)), so now we are trying to see if there is something else we could do on the OData part to get some improvements in the response time.
I was wondering if you have any suggestion on what we could look into moving forward, something that maybe was included in the newer versions of Microsoft.Odata library(maybe some serializer or deserializer).

Also, is there a possibility that the dynamic model generation could affect the performance( my initial performance report done in Visual Studio shows that it doesn't impact performance, taking some ms to create).

Thanks

Comment: it's too broad of a question and you aren't providing any real quantifiable information (which would be somewhat difficult to do in this forum).  you're handling ~23 requests a sec by the numbers you've provided (as it relates to this client doing 1 million requests over 12 hours).  what do those requests look like? what is the overhead to authentication and authorization? do you have a load balancer or any caching going on?

Comment: @BrettCaswell, thanks. I know this is a very broad question, it's because our solution is very customised, using its own framework solution over the .net framework, so it would be impossible for me to provide a specific example. Basically, the requests are mainly GET or PUT requests, some gets can be a little big(3-6MB initally, but we added http compression). We have a load balancer, and caching is done in memory( for some metadata and we also cache the edmmodel). There's a usertoken that is stored on the session so it doesn't impact in any way the requests(after the initial one)

Comment: apart from those infrastructure concerns, the odata repo on github suggests using Microsoft.Crank when running performance benchmarking.  As such, my advice is to run a benchmark on a staging environment (that is equivalent to production environment in terms of hardware) and gather/prepare any architectural-related material and resources.

Comment: hmm... it's negligible, but all passed data is processed in some respect... session tokens are typically processed on every request and detokenized to an identity.  In respect to access tokens, they too will be evaluated for validity and expiration on every request.